# How does React's useState change the value of a constant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

This is the syntax I'm working with.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount((count + 1));
  };
```

I understand that setCount is creating an instance of count, but I'm really not grasping how exactly count is being changed if it's a constant or how, if it's an instance, it's able to be called and return the most recent value.

Wouldn't every time React re-renders the page, it reads the constant count first?

It's working just fine for me, but I can't wrap my head around why.

Comment: `Wouldn't every time React re-renders the page, it reads the constant count first?` No. Because react uses a `fibre` behind the scenes to keep track of all the component instances and their members. When you update the count, you're updating the instance member on that fibre (the component instance) Your functional component is actually a class (with instance variables), it just doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 1):

`count` is 'constant' for the duration of the function. When `setCount()` is called, the local `count` doesn't change. Eventually your component gets rendered again with the new value.

During this new render the `count` is updated, but it will again be constant for the duration of the render/function.